# Show only posts related to category or page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

I'm kinda new to wordpress and was wondering if I could do the following:

Let's say I have a site for a bakery and in the mainmenu on top there are four links: 
Home - About - Products - Contact

Under the page products I would have a number of posts : Bread, cupcakes, ..etc. all of these posts would be categorized under the category products. Now if I go to the products page I want to see only these posts in a sidebar. Therefor I have two questions:

- How can I connect this category to this page
- How can I show the posts from this category in a sidebar

If anything is unclear please feel free to ask me, also if you would suggest another way of working please let me know.

Much appreciated, thanks!

[EDIT]
I have found that it is better to add a category for this products category instead of a page. Now I'm still looking to display a static post as an intro for this products category.

Comment: you are developing theme?

Comment: Well not yet, but I'll probably start by using the twenty-twelve theme for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connect this category to this page

- you can set product to category archive page from
  `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`
- you can create a simple page template to list category post
- you can    use http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/    plugin and use    short code like `[catlist name="news"]` in you page content.